# Security Без Spring'a в REST Api

Tags: java, java-ee, авторизация, rest, аутентификация

В проекте был написан фильтр авторизации через токены, но без использования spring-security.

Это обычный класс `RestAuthenticationFilter`, который наследуется от `Filter` и записывается в проперти `web.xml`.

Теперь нужно доделать секюрити, написать какой-то конфиг файл, который работал бы как `spring-context.xml`. Проверял юзера до права доступа к тому или иному url.

Кроме этого в spring-security, можно проверить, какой пользователь сейчас вошел с помощью `Principal`, но в этом случае этот вариант не пройдет.

Вопросы:

1. Как в таком RESTful Api с кастомным секюрити, дописать свой конфиг файл, который будет задавать доступ юзеров к материалам?
2. Как можно проверять  такой системе, вошедшего пользователя и выдавать о нем всю информацию(username, password, email .... )?

**Update**

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filter) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest httprequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    final HttpServletResponse httpresponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    final HttpSession session = httprequest.getSession();
    boolean isNewSession = session.isNew();
    AccountInfo accountInfo = null;
    if (isNewSession) {
        log.debug("New Session get user Info");
        try {

            accountInfo = this.isAuthenticated(httprequest, httpresponse);
            if (accountInfo != null) {

                session.setAttribute("accountInfo", accountInfo);
                request.setAttribute("accountInfo", accountInfo);
                request.setAttribute(SM_USER, accountInfo.getUserName());
                System.out.println("AND WHERE IS THIS FUCKIN USER?!!!!");
            } else {
                httpresponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            httprequest.setAttribute("message",
                    "Please contact your administrator to get an access to this application "
                            + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    } else {
        accountInfo = (AccountInfo) session.getAttribute("accountInfo");
        if (accountInfo == null || accountInfo.getAccountId() == null
                || accountInfo.getAccountId() <= 0) {
            // ReValidate
            try {
                accountInfo = this.isAuthenticated(httprequest,
                        httpresponse);
                if (accountInfo != null) {

                    session.setAttribute("accountInfo", accountInfo);
                    request.setAttribute("accountInfo", accountInfo);
                    request.setAttribute(SM_USER, accountInfo.getUserName());
                } else {
                    httpresponse
                            .setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                    httprequest.setAttribute("message",
                            "Please contact your administrator to get an access to this application "
                                    + "Invalid User Info");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                httprequest.setAttribute("message",
                        "Please contact your administrator to get an access to this application "
                                + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }

        } else {
            request.setAttribute(SM_USER, accountInfo.getUserName());
            request.setAttribute("accountInfo",
                    session.getAttribute("accountInfo"));
            accountInfo = (AccountInfo) session.getAttribute("accountInfo");
            log.debug("user in old Session");

        }
    }

    // Get user from session
    // Set User Context info
    try {
        if (session.getAttribute("accountInfo") != null) {
            AccountService acctService = springContext
                    .getBean(AccountService.class);
            AccountInfo info = (AccountInfo) session
                    .getAttribute("accountInfo");
            if (info.getAccountId() != null) {
                Account val = acctService.get(accountInfo.getAccountId());
                ProfileContext.setAccountContext(val);
            }
            // Set this user Name to log4j MDC
            MDC.put("userName", AbstractServiceModel
                    .formatUserDetails(ProfileContext.getProfileContext()));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("Invalid user information" + e);
        return;
    }

    if (httprequest.getRequestURI() != null
            && httprequest.getRequestURI().contains("logoutApp")) {
        session.invalidate();
    }

    filter.doFilter(request, response);

    // End setting
    // remove context
    this.destroy();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Просто придумываете свой формат конфигурации: xml, json, properties - все, что хотите. Конфиг может соотносить, например, роли пользователей и разрешенные им URL-ы. При старте приложения грузите его в память. Фильтр проверяет каждый запрос на соответствие роли текущего пользователя URL-у.
2. Сделайте так же, как это реализовано в Spring Security. У них есть класс `SecurityContextHolder` со статическим thread-local полем, в котором хранится информация о пользователе. Это поле заполняется как раз в фильтре после прохождения аутентификации и доступно в текущем потоке из любого класса. Если упрощенно:

   ```
   public class SecurityContextHolder {
       private static final ThreadLocal<UserInfo> userInfoHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();

       public static UserInfo getUserInfo() {
           return (UserInfo)userInfoHolder.get();
       }

       public static void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {
           userInfoHolder.set(userInfo);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: по второму вопросу, это просто нужно создать этот класс и передавать в `ThreadLocal` свое ентити, и потом вызывать этот класс в контроллере и вытягивать с  него контекст юзера? Правильно?

Comment: Да, примерно так.

Comment: еще один вопрос по первому. 
в этом проекте и каждого юзера есть своя роль, которая идет отдельным `enum` (ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_DOCTOR, и тд). 
Я нашел в доках вариант кастомного секюрити с помощью тегов `<security-constraint>` в `web.xml`. Но как заставить эти конфигурации понимать какая роль у юзера? Где оно ее чекает? Я логинуюсь как админ, а права доступа все равно не получаю

Comment: Если вы используете `<security-constraint>`, то проверкой прав занимается контейнер (Tomcat) и в вашей кастомной секьюрити пропадает смысл.

Comment: То есть вам нужно определиться: использовать средства безопасности J2EE или городить свои велосипеды.

Comment: нашел в документациях еще один вариант `Securing RESTful Web Services Using SecurityContext`, он подойдет для этого? Ну в случае если `<security-constraint>` нету смысла делать.

Comment: Как способ дотянуться до Principal - вполне. Но кто-то должен его туда подставить. В любом случае придется разбираться с настройкой авторизации в томкате.

Comment: @trembling11 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey

Comment: @Sergey мне не нужно написать систему авторизации. Она уже написана. Нужно только дописать `interrupt filter`, который бы мог определять те роли, которые есть в юзера и по ним давать доступ к разным `url`.

Comment: @Nofate ну я свой томкат то настрою локальный, а как быть с тем, что на сервере, получается там так же нужно будет изменять эти конфигурации. 
аааа. что так сложно.

Comment: Таков мир JavaEE, там нужно конфигурировать application-сервера у заказчика )

Comment: @trembling11 мне показалось, что там изложены идеи как прокинуть свою авторизацию в авторизацию контейнерную, дотянуться до principal. тогда можно воспользоваться <security-constraint>. На досуге почитаю внимательней. Тоже есть задумка с токеном

Comment: @Sergey да, вижу. не увидел, когда первый раз посмотрел. спасибо, сейчас почитаю.

Comment: @Nofate а в чем вообще может быть прикол, в аппликухе, когда ты логинишся, то все окей. то есть твой личный кабинет и тд. 
с той частью кода с которой я работаю, у меня не открываются сессии.  то есть используют `swagger`, чтобы удобно ходить по урлам но когда я отправляю `json' для авторизации, мне возвращается `login successful` и все. на самом деле никакого логина не было. просто вернулась строка, которая проверила, что такой юзер есть в базе. как в таких условиях написать фильтры секюрити и их потестить?

Comment: @trembling11 Здесь нужен прежде всего свой нестандартный механизм аутентификации (через токен). Какого-то стандарта нет, у каждого сервера своё API для этого дела. Это как фильтр, только не в приложении, а в системе. Потом уже дело доходит до модулей авторизации. Здесь уже есть какой-то стандарт и не так уж всё страшно

Comment: @Nofate я апдейтнул вопрос. У меня в этом кастомном фильтре, стоит какая-то проверка юзера. Можете подсказать, что там вообще происходит? И как мне это может помочь?)) и нужно ли тогда переписывать что-то или можно использовать `это`)

Comment: Мимокрокодил: я правильно понимаю, что подход из пункта два не предполагает существования реактивного приложения?